# How can i get the registered-date from Firebase Auth in Vue3?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I need to access the createdAt variable to convert it via date() to a real date. But somehow, i can't access it by auth.currentUser.createdAt variable.
How can i do that?

Short example

```
const date = ref('')
date.value = new Date(auth.currentUser.metadata.createdAt)
                //  1676566043721 is interpreted as invalid date
```

It does not work because new Date is at the same time rendered, as the value received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface) doesn't have a `createdAt` property. you're probably looking for `auth.currentUser.metadata.creationTime`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i convert the number in metadata.createdAt with toDate()? It seems deprecated.

Comment: `metadata.creationTime` returns a string according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata.md#usermetadatacreationtime). If you can't get the code to work, it's much more likely we can help if you edit your question to show the [minimal code that allows any of us to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example).